# Extract strings between two special charecter($) using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

Input:  `"abcdef$ghi$jklmno$pqrst$ wx $yx$"`

Expected output:

```
<tokens>
<token>$ghi$</token>
<token>$pqrst</token>
<token>$yx$</token>
</tokens>
```

As per sample input string, output must be like Expected output by using XSLT 1.0

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please *kindly* post the code to show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

For each pair of dollar signs (1,2), (3,4), ... (2 × *n* - 1, 2 × *n*) you want a token element with the text between dollar sign number 2 × *n* - 1 and dollar sign number 2 *n*.

One of two cases will necessarily apply.

Case 1: there is some fixed maximum value of *n*, and it's relatively small (say, less than 5 or 10).  In this case a simple sequence of `xs:variable` assignments with appropriate calls to `substring-before` and `substring-after` should suffice, and you're done.  You'll end up with something like this:

- Let *s0* be the original string, *s1* the substring after the first dollar sign in *s0*,  *t1* the substring before the first dollar sign in *s1*, and *r1* the substring after the first dollar sign in *s1*.
- Now let *s2* be the substring after the first dollar sign in *r1*, *t2* the substring before the first dollar sign in *s2*, and *r2* the substring after the first dollar sign in *s2*.
- Repeat as needed:  for *i* in 3 to *n*, let *s<sub>i</sub>* be the substring after the first dollar sign in *r*<sub>*i* - 1</sub>, *t<sub>i</sub>* the substring before the first dollar sign in *s<sub>i</sub>*, and *r<sub>i</sub>* the substring after the first dollar sign in *s<sub>i</sub>*.

Case 2:  there is no maximum *n*. In this case the straightforward approach in XSLT 1.0 is to write a named template which (a) drops the substring before the first dollar sign, (b) constructs a `token` element containing a dollar sign, the string after the first dollar sign and before second dollar sign, and (c) calls itself recursively with the substring after the second dollar sign.  Add appropriate boundary conditions for empty strings, strings with odd numbers of dollar signs, and other input errors, and you're done.

So:  go read up on the string functions of XSLT 1.0 and solve your problem.  Come back (and show your work) if you have further trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below xsl helps you. It works. I tried it myself.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="input">
        <xsl:text>abcdef$ghi$jklmno$pqrst$ wx$yx$</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <tokens>    
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="(\$[a-z]+\$)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <token>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                </token>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </tokens>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Kate but we have to do it using XSLT 1.0 and if i am not wrong then your solution is in XSLT 2.0